# To conduct approximate matching (Fuzzy) in R

Tags: r, analytics, fuzzy-search, text-extraction

I have a large data set, dedicated to stock market prices & information. Because the data isn't ready for end-analytics, I am right now in the data-cleaning stage to make it ready to use for analysis & modelling.

Since the information in the cells doesn't all follow a single format sorted already. It contains a collection of different patterns, all of which I need to account for.

Ex.

COLUMN PURPOSE

1. DIVIDEND-RE.1/- PER SHARE
2. AGM/DIV-RS.3.50 PER SHARE
3. SPL DIV-RS.2.70 PER SHARE
4. DIV - FIN 3.50RE PER SHARE + SPL-Rs.1.4
5. FV SPLIT Rs.10 to RE.1
6. BON 3:2 + SPLT Rs. 5 to Rs.2.5
7. BONUS 4:1
8. DIV:10%

**So I want a fuzzy logic approach to check for the presence of SPLIT, DIVIDEND, BONUS and which ever cell the pattern match occurs in the column PURPOSE, I need the index position of that particular pattern in string to extract the numerical value following it.**

**Is there any way in R to determine if the patterns can be checked and matched approximately while returning for value - the indices for the same in the respective strings?** 
**(such that if in case the symbols change furthermore in the future according to the government website's notation in the data storage, or the format/positioning/spacing changes - it could account for all those changes automatically.)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative you can consider, though it does not reply the question as it is   :

1. Get name changes from NSE website as a csv : 
   https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/content/securities_info.htm
2. use the package `quantmod` Get splits and dividends from yahoo

   getDividends("INFY.NS",from = "2000-01-01") ;
   getSplits("INFY.NS",from = "2000-01-01")